# Default fonts for React native hole app BY calling one time fonts name

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to use a **Font** for all place or full app.

I don't want to call it too much time.

**It should be call one time SO is it Possible ??**

AS Like:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```

I all ready get some Type Answer Like that's..
BY Calling **Costume Components**
and By calling Global Style like...

```
<Text style={{styles.text}}> Demo </ Text>

const style= { 
  style: { 
    fontFamily: yourFont
  }
}
```

But I don't want too use it like this way ..

Please give me any Update Answer or News...

Which help me to solve it BY Call one time..

**NB:** I all ready Complete my App 80%... It's have lot off View SO How can I get a **Fonts** everywhere by call one time anywhere.

Comment: Any reason for you not wanting to create a custom component, set the font family for that, and use that component instead of `Text` in your app? It's a nice approach, since you can assign other properties to that component as well that are immediately reflected to the whole app.

Comment: @NiFi Right, We Need a perfect solution which way we can solve it for whole app.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you are seeking is not directly possible as it is antithetical to React principles of isolated components. IMO the best approach is to create a custom component and use it to "replace" the `Text` component in your app. It's even possible to use Text as name for that component, and just change imports accordingly.

```
export default class Text extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.defaultText}>{this.props.children}</Text>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  defaultText: {
    fontFamily: 'System'
  }
});
```

Then simply change imports in the components you want to use this font, from

```
import { Text } from 'react-native';
```

to

```
import Text from './Text.js';
```

Comment: Good Way Before Get any Global style for react-native component ..
Thanks @Nifi